# gnuplot: multiplot with "pause mouse close" skips a plot

Tags: gnuplot

I've noticed that multiplot in gnuplot, when using "pause mouse close" to display a plot and then quit, only plots the second plot.  (Thisis gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3 on Ubuntu 16.04.)  Compare this

```
cat <<EOF | gnuplot
set multiplot
set size 0.4,0.4
set origin 0.1,0.1
plot sin(x)
set size 0.2,0.2
set origin 0.5,0.5
plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
pause mouse close
EOF
```

with this

```
cat <<EOF | gnuplot -persist
set multiplot
set size 0.4,0.4
set origin 0.1,0.1
plot sin(x)
set size 0.2,0.2
set origin 0.5,0.5
plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
EOF
```

I've not found anything relevant in the docs or on the Net.  Anyone have any pointers if this is my error or a bug?

Comment: I can confirm this with 5.0.3, but in 5.1 (cvs) this is fixed. However, I cannot find the respective commit or bug report.